# Tell what kind of curve is traced by the particle(Be specific!!)

Tags: calculus

I'm a Junior(16) and this question is killing me please help!!!

b > 0 and c > 0 are constants and a particle moves with acceleration given by a(t)=<0,-c^2cos(ct),-c^2sin(ct)> ￼and initial velocity v(t)=< b , 0, c >.

Q1. Find the position function.
Q2. Tell what kind of curve is traced by the particle(Be specific!!).
Q3. Find the curvature(k) of the curve(The answer can contain b and/or c).
Q4. How would the motion of the particle change if b were zero??

Solving one of them would be great! Solving all would be ajksdfadsj!!
Can't express it in words.

I really need help on Q2 and Q4. The ones of motions.

Comment: This is straightforward - you are given the components of the acceleration vector $\overline{a}(t)$. Integrate once with respect to $t$ and you'll get the velocity. Integrate the velocity and you get the position.

Comment: I don't know if you are still here or not but did you get 1/sqrt(b^2+c^2) for Q3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q2: Integrating twice and satisfying v at t=0, you'll get the position vector as $<bt, -\cos ct, \sin ct>$. If you think of $\theta = ct$, this is clearly a unit circle in the y-z plane, but since the x coordinate keeps increasing with time, $bt$, the curve is a helix.

Comment: for  <bt,−cosct,sinct>, don't you need constant of integration after each coordinate?

Comment: @lovemathsbuttoohard Yes, you can have an arbitrary translation of the position solution by a constant vector $<a_1, a_2, a_3>$ but to find those numbers you'll require some more data, like initial position at which the particle starts at time t=0; this is not given in your problem. For example, if you assume the particle starts at position $0,0,0$ at $t=0$, you'll have $a_2 = 1$, $a_1 = a_3 =0$. Won't change the nature of the curve.

Comment: okay I got it. thanks very much!